# Ubuntu 13.04 Bluetooth Adapter Identified but Cannot Detect Devices

Tags: wireless, 13.04, 64-bit, bluetooth

Alright, so a little back story before the question.  I ordered an [awesome controller](http://www.evolutioncontrollers.com/) a half a year back and have since awaited its arrival.  Well it arrived today and I was extremely excited.. until I tried to use it.

The controller connects to devices via Bluetooth and for the past two or three hours I've done internet sweeps and Google searches looking for and testing hopeful solutions to my problem:

My bluetooth adapter is present, but it continually searches for devices never finding them.  I've experimented with various package installs following online instructions given that I've only used Ubuntu (and Linux in general) for a little under a month.  I tried installing blueman and other bluetooth packages in an effort to get the device to be detected.

I also verified it wasn't a hardware defect in the device itself.  I took a bluetooth phone and paired the controller effortlessly.  I also attempted to pair the phone with my computer, but it didn't work either with the same results: the computer cannot detect the phone, nor can the phone detect the computer.

I should note that I've used bluetooth without issue with Windows 7, but that shouldn't matter, should it? :P

Since reading so many plausible solutions gave me an idea of what might be asked of me I'll include a few things here:

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0149 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:1000 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0159 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Digital Media Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

hcitool dev

```
hci0    70:F3:95:74:18:B8
```

rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[Here is some information about my bluetooth adapter.](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ralink_RT3090BC4_Reference_Design)

I recall reading something about trouble with devices that bundle bluetooth and wifi... but I don't know if it's of any significance here.

I also think it's curious that I have two bluetooth devices showing up in the `rfkill list` command..  Could that have something to do with the problem?

A quick recap of the problem:

- Bluetooth Adapter Present
- Searches for Devices but none can be found
- Is searched for (visibility enabled) but can't be found by other bluetooth devices

I'd love any help anyone could give me as I really don't know my way around Ubuntu very well yet.  That and I'd really like to test out the new controller. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a real solution to the problem, but I'd definitely try a different bluetooth adapter if I were you. 
Doesn't cost much to try a different adaptor:

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Mini-V2-0-EDR-USB-2-0-Bluetooth-Dongle-Wireless-Adapter-/270931375927?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item3f14c4b737

Also in the interest of saving time I'd pay a little extra to order one from within your country, or just go down to the mall and find something in a discount store.

Often in Linux, a device will show up in lspci or lsusb and does have a driver, but the drivers have issues and don't fully function, or don't function at all.

Also from what I've read, certain functions of Bluetooth in Linux are, well, not functioning! I find that some devices can't be detected, or can't be paired.

For any hardware device, often times some functions of a device don't work, while others do.
One thing I like about Linux is that certain devices that don't work Windows do actually work in Linux. But that's usually for legacy devices, and often times it will take a long time for new devices to be supported in Linux if at all.

Comment: Yea.  I kinda figured that if I can't get the on-board bluetooth to work I'll go out and buy a dongle.  On the plus side, if I do that, computers that don't natively support bluetooth would be able to use my controller so it might be a win-win to purchase one anyway.

If I don't manage to get my on-board working, oh well.  But if I do and I have the dongle, at least I can have portability across multiple computers.  Thanks for the response.  I'll keep looking, but in the mean time I think I'm visiting Walmart. :P